# how to block all images on server .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ - [F]
```

Images can be accessed. I tried so:

```
deny from all
```

and still does not work, the images are continuing available

So just go on https but http does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On`? Do you have other rewrite rules in this .htaccess file? Are you using https  such that the http:// would not match?

Comment: Try this one: RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]

Comment: Also, are the first two `RewriteCond` being satisfied?

Comment: `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite\.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F]` still not working

Comment: I have this and it works: 

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} login\.php
RewriteRule login.php [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]`

Comment: Can you copy/paste your full .htaccess in your question.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]` So just go on https but http does not work.